# Pointer changes value for no reason c++

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I am trying to store a pointer as a member variable, so that during the life of the class, other functions can work with the pointer.

However, when I first setup this class, the pointer variable is correct for the first printf, but when the second one is called, the value is 0x0

In my main, setup is called once first, and then update is called repeatedly.

member variables are declared in the h file.

why does the pointer change between the first and second printf?

//Main//

```
int Main(){

TestClass testclass;

unsigned char array[1000];
unsigned char * pVideoIn = array;

testclass.setup(pVideoIn);

for (int i =0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    testclass.update();
    }
}
```

//header//

```
#ifndef _TEST_CLASS
#define _TEST_CLASS

class TestClass {

public:
void setup(unsigned char* videoIn); 
void update();

unsigned char* videoInp;
unsigned char* videoOutp;

int noPixels; 
};

#endif
```

//class//

```
#include "TestClass.h"

void TestClass::setup(unsigned char* videoIn)
{
videoInp = videoIn;
videoOutp = videoOut;
noPixels = pixels;

printf("in class app = %p \n", videoInp);

}

void TestClass::update()
{ 
printf("in class app = %p \n", videoInp); 
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete test case that can be compiled and run.  The most important missing piece of information is how you are allocating object(s) of type `TestClass`, but posting only another fragment that shows that is NOT enough.  Please post a complete test case that can be compiled and run.

Comment: Since your pointers are public, is there a chance you're modifying them anywhere else in your code?  Why don't you make them private?

Comment: I'll add how I'm allocating the class now. I could have the variable private. It is definitely not being changed elsewhere though.

Comment: And this compiles? Declaration doesn't have default values for `videoOut` and `pixels`.

Comment: You are calling `testclass.setup(pVideoIn);` while declaring `void setup(unsigned char* videoIn, unsigned char* videoOut, int noPixels);` - that's fishy. Do you have another constructor in that class that is not implemented correctly?

Comment: Why aren't you using constructor and initialization list? And why are you making a new pointer, just to call a function with it? `Use testclass.setup(array);`

Comment: I just decided not to use a constructor for now. I didn't see any harm in that? I also thought it was a very simple test, so I'm not using initialization list. I'm using another pointer just to make it clearer what I'm doing.

Comment: @Roman I have changed this now, I've modified the code to make it a clear example here.

Comment: 1. This code doesn't compile
2. When compilation is fixed it doesn't exhibit the problem described

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, and after fixing minor compilation errors (by supplying NULL and 0 as the other arguments to setup, for example), the code as presented does not exhibit the behaviour you describe when I run it. In particular, it prints out the same non-NULL pointer 101 times. Conclusion: this is not the code you're having trouble with (you need to post an example that actually exhibits the problem).

Comment: The code i'm working with involves using openframeworks, so I didn't want to confuse the issue. I'm pretty sure this covers what I'm doing, but I'll review and see if I can add anything more.

Comment: @optician: It's fine to post code other than the actual code if it's inappropriate to do that for some reason, but the code you post has to actually fail in the same way or it's a waste of time.

Comment: Your right, I just copied the code above into a small new project, and it seemed to do what I want! Ok back to the drawing board or another question.

Answer (score 3):

I know this one is a bit old, and it's impossible to to provide a solution for this specific problem, since it cannot be recreated with the code provided, but I recently bumped into something similar, and thought I'd share some rather general tips regarding how to go about solving this.

Basically: be careful with arrays.
I forgot about this as programming for Java and C# made me a bit lazy: you don't get an IndexOutOfBoundsException in c++, the program just goes to whatever memory location you tell it to, and modifies it accordingly.
If you're lucky, you'll get an Access Violation error then and there, as the program attempts to write to a location that is outside of what the OS has allocated for it.
If you're not lucky, it will modify a part of the memory that belongs to it, messing up whatever pointers, variables or objects you've declared.